# Not post Value from view to controller using ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I check in my controller I get null value.

Below is the list of inputs that are taken from user and want to send using ajax.

View page input box

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VALUE[1].Name);
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VALUE[2].Name);
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VALUE[3].Name);
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VALUE[4].Name);
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VALUE[5].Name);
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VALUE[6].Name);

<script>
var data = {
'VALUE_1__Name': $("#VALUE_1__Name").val(),
'VALUE_2__Name': $("#VALUE_2__Name").val(),
'VALUE_3__Name': $("#VALUE_3__Name").val(),
'VALUE_4__Name': $("#VALUE_4__Name").val(),
'VALUE_5__Name': $("#VALUE_5__Name").val(),
'VALUE_6__Name': $("#VALUE_6__Name").val(),

        }

  $(document).ready(function () {
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@(Url.Action("Create", "Data"))",
            data: data,
            traditional: true,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

            }           
        });
   });
</script>
```

Post data into controller using

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Model model)
{
}
```

Now how to get value from view to controller?

Comment: What is the controller method your posting back to? The only way this could bind is if you had `public ActionResult Create(string AvaiablePassenger_1__Name)`

Comment: i have bulk list that i want to send so it not possible to use single paramater

Comment: What bulk list? All you have shown is your posting a single value (with a name of `AvaiablePassenger_1__Name`! (and you model does not contain a property named `AvaiablePassenger_1__Name` so there is nothing to bind). Edit your question to explain what your really trying to do

Comment: The controls you have shown have indexers which start at `1` - the `DefaultModelBinder` requires that indexers start at zero and be consecutive (unless you have included a special input for the value of the indexer). If you have generated you form correctly (using `for (int i = 0; i < Model.AvaiablePassenger.Count; i++ ) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AvaiablePassenger[i].Name) }` then you can just use `data: $('form').serialize(),` to serialize you form (and you need to remove the `traditional: true,` option)

Comment: @StephenMuecke well it looks bad as hell indeed, but it might've solved OP's problem

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="myForm">
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VALUE[1].Name);
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VALUE[2].Name);
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VALUE[3].Name);
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VALUE[4].Name);
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VALUE[5].Name);
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VALUE[6].Name);
</form>

<script>
      var data = {
'VALUE_1__Name': $("#VALUE_1__Name").val(),
'VALUE_2__Name': $("#VALUE_2__Name").val(),
'VALUE_3__Name': $("#VALUE_3__Name").val(),
'VALUE_4__Name': $("#VALUE_4__Name").val(),
'VALUE_5__Name': $("#VALUE_5__Name").val(),
'VALUE_6__Name': $("#VALUE_6__Name").val(),
    }
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@(Url.Action("Create", "Data"))",
        data: data,
        traditional: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

        }           
     });
   });
</script>
```

> Post data into controller using

```
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection fc)
{
     ViewBag.name1 = fc["VALUE_1__Name"];
     ViewBag.name2 = fc["VALUE_2__Name"];
     ViewBag.name3 = fc["VALUE_3__Name"];
     ViewBag.name4 = fc["VALUE_4__Name"];
     ViewBag.name5 = fc["VALUE_5__Name"];
     ViewBag.name6 = fc["VALUE_6__Name"];
        return View("Index");
}
```